# Pass username to systemd unit running as root

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to write my first systemd unit. I want to dynamically mount some places based on the username at login like /mnt/$USER/folder and not though fstab. I cannot get $USER or $LOGNAME to the script via systemd because root user is required to issue the mount command so those always expand to "root".

I have tried Environment=, EnvironmentFile=, passing $USER in ExecStart instead of in the called script, and they all pass "$USER" literally rather than the actual username. If I run the service as a user, the mount fails because the user isn't root.

I'm hoping not to reconfigure the entire system for this one task.

Any suggestions?

Comment: to me this sounds like a task for pam_mount (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/pam_mount.8.html), not systemd.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. Sounds like exactly what I need. I didn't want to use xinit like in the past.